# Is it possible to fire Automated Calls using the Twilio API , play a message and receive responses with digits?

Tags: ios, api, twilio

Is it possible to fire Automated Question Pool Calls using Twilio so that the person who answer the call, after hearing a message "say verb", answer the question with digits from 0 to 9? "gather verb"?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio evangelist here.

Since your question is tagged with iOS, I assume your asking if you can do this in an iPhone app.  Using Twilio its possible to do what you want, but I would highly recommend doing this all on the server-side, not from an iOS app.

The [Phone Poll](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/phonepoll) How To will walk you through creating a simple phone poll system.

Hope that helps.